# cell separated overlapping overlapping cell iOS

Tags: ios, tableview

I have a table view in an iPhone app.  I have two dynamic custom cells crated and a cell seperater in between both of them.  The storyboard shows only cells but the separater is coded in the app.  The separater is overalpping the second cell and covering part of the top including some text.  What can I do to fix this overlap?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *c=nil;
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AreaCell";
        LSAreaCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        APLArea *area=[self getAreaForIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.areaImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:area.imageName1];
        c=cell;
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *QuoteCellIdentifier = @"QuoteCellIdentifier";

        APLQuoteCell *cell = (APLQuoteCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:QuoteCellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"binding_light"]];

        cell.subarea = [self getSubareaForIndexPath:indexPath];
        c=cell;

        //I put in a seperator on aug 14.  it was supposed to be released!!!
        UIView *cellSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 ,35)];
        [cellSeparator setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
        [cellSeparator setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTopLeft];
        [cellSeparator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"spacer"]]];
        [cell addSubview:cellSeparator];

       // self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"binding_light"]];
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want this custom separator fully in between both of the cells?

If so then you can you basically need to first set the tableview separator style as shown

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

Then you must incorporate enough space in your table view cells to accommodate the separator.You can either increase the height of each cell or make the separator smaller to fix the overlap. These changes will occur in initWithFrame on your separator or cellWithHeight for the tableview

Comment: Yes, I want it fully between both cells.  So if I understand correctly then the overlap is normal?  Separators always overlap cells adjacent to them?    Then and I should fix it by just making the cell bigger and moving my labels down? I think that will work. I will check and mark your answer correct then.

Comment: Yes, if you are just adding it as a subview of a cell, that cell frame doesnt actually change. So you need to take that additional space for the separator into account in the cell height. Awesome. Thanks